# Detecting Zero Crossing in Image Filtered by Laplacian Operator

Tags: image-processing, filters, convolution, lowpass-filter

This is my first question on this site, complete noob. But here goes.

I have a positive Laplacian operator

```
[[0,1,0],
 [1,-4,1],
 [0,1,0]]
```

Now this Laplacian operator is used to find the outward edges of an image , IIRC. The image which I have in binary format is this

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Its hard to make out here, but the image represents some staircase type of  image. I have a PY script which does the `convolve` and gives me back the following result of convolution :

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Drawing straight line through all `1s` actually does give me the outward edge of the binary image.

However, the zero crossing algorithm has confused me .
According to this [link](http://www.coe.utah.edu/~cs4640/slides/Lecture8.pdf) , the algorithm to detect zero crossing is:

> Do the following for each pixel $I(u, v)$:
>
> 1. Look at your four neighbors, left, right, up and down
> 2. If they all have the same sign as you, then you are not a zero crossing
> 3. Else, if you have the smallest absolute value compared to your neighbors with opposite sign, then you are a zero crossing

But here, the `0` and `1` have the same signs , right ? Both are positive. I am confused in this. 
If someone can take a small sample out of the result image, and mark some zero crossing for me, it will be clear to me.

Thank you in advance, it's a long post. I hope its clear though.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake. 
My PY script was thresholded to output `1` if pixel value was above `0.5`, and `0` if otherwise.
Removing the threshold, I got the following result

`

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2. -3.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2. -2. -1.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  2. -2.  0. -1.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  0.  2. -2.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  2. -2.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  2. -2.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.],
 [ 1. -3. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -2.  1.  0.],
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

`

Here I can find the transition between negative and positive pixels easily.

Damn you coding...